# Combining pandas dataframes with same and different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have problems while combining a list of DataFrames in Python. First of all I got a unknown number amount of  DataFrames which are stored during a for-loop as follows:

```
appendDataFrames.append(df)
```

These DataFrames have 5 columns that are always the same: `|static_1|static_2|static_3|static_4|static_5|...` after those 5 columns there can be a set of columns between 5 up to 400 columns. I don't know beforehand about the column-set  and their naming, but it can happen that some columns have equal names over the hole set of DataFrames.

Now I want to create a overall DataFrame which contains these 5 static columns and afterwards all other columns. If values for a column are not present in one sub-DataFrame it should contain NaN e.g.

Such as follows:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
u'0.17.1'
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 8.59, 7.64], [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 10.5, 17.64]],
...                    columns=['static_1', 'static_2', 'static_3', 'static_4', 'static_5',
...                    'c1', 'c2'])
>>> df1
   static_1  static_2  static_3  static_4  static_5     c1     c2
0         1         2         1         2         1   8.59   7.64
1         1         2         1         2         1  10.50  17.64
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 100.56, 1.58], [3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 0.50, 1.68]],
...                    columns=['static_1', 'static_2', 'static_3', 'static_4', 'static_5',
...                    'c1', 'c3'])
>>> df2
   static_1  static_2  static_3  static_4  static_5      c1    c3
0         3         4         3         4         3  100.56  1.58
1         3         4         3         4         3    0.50  1.68
```

Now I want to merge, concat, append, join or whatever to get a superset of all combined DataFrame `resultDf` like:

```
>>> resultDf
   static_1  static_2  static_3  static_4  static_5      c1     c2    c3
0         1         2         1         2         1    8.59   7.64   NaN
1         1         2         1         2         1   10.50  17.64   NaN
2         3         4         3         4         3  100.56    NaN  1.58
3         3         4         3         4         3    0.50    NaN  1.68
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full&clean answer with reference to the **index** of the final df:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=False)
```

Result:
[image]

You can see the **problem with the index column.**

For **resolving this issue:**

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Final result:
[image: final result df]

Answer (score 0):

You just got to use `pd.concat()` like

```
>>> dataframes = []
>>> dataframes.append(df1)
>>> dataframes.append(df2)
>>> dataframes
[   static_1  static_2  static_3  static_4  static_5     c1     c2
0         1         2         1         2         1   8.59   7.64
1         1         2         1         2         1  10.50  17.64,    static_1  static_2  static_3  static_4  static_5      c1    c3
0         3         4         3         4         3  100.56  1.58
1         3         4         3         4         3    0.50  1.68]
>>> dataframes[0]
   static_1  static_2  static_3  static_4  static_5     c1     c2
0         1         2         1         2         1   8.59   7.64
1         1         2         1         2         1  10.50  17.64
>>> dataframes[1]
   static_1  static_2  static_3  static_4  static_5      c1    c3
0         3         4         3         4         3  100.56  1.58
1         3         4         3         4         3    0.50  1.68
>>> result = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
>>> result
       c1     c2    c3  static_1  static_2  static_3  static_4  static_5
0    8.59   7.64   NaN         1         2         1         2         1
1   10.50  17.64   NaN         1         2         1         2         1
2  100.56    NaN  1.58         3         4         3         4         3
3    0.50    NaN  1.68         3         4         3         4         3
```